# Converting a local control in XAML to C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, controls

I'm doing a WPF application that shows images in a Pivot, and added a small control to show at the bottom of the screen all the images in small icons, When I test it with some simple images it all Works, once I add the code that reads the server, and processes the files the control doesn’t Works, because it’s no longer called once I dynamically add the pivot items.

XAML Code:

```
<local:PivoteLocationView="{Binding ElementName=pivot}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                          Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

<controls:Pivot Margin="0,-30,0,40" 
                x:Name="pivot">
  <controls:PivotItem>
    ...
  </controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

C# code that will add the pivotitems

```
    pivot.Items.Clear();
    for (i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle();
        var btxt = new TextBlock();
        var stackend = new StackPanel();
        var PIend = new PivotItem();

        ... code that assigns values

        stacktend.Children.Add(rect);
        stacktend.Children.Add(btxt);

        PIend.Content = stacktend;

        pivot.Items.Add(pantodo);

    }
```

The control:

```
public class PivotLocationViewModel
{
  private Pivot _pivot;

  public PivotLocationViewModel()
  {
  }

  public PivotLocationViewModel(Pivot pivot)
  {
    PivotItems = new PivotItemViewModelCollection();
    SetPivot(pivot);
  }

public PivotItemViewModelCollection PivotItems { get; set; }

  private void SetPivot(Pivot pivot)
  {
    _pivot = pivot;

    // handle selection changed
    pivot.SelectionChanged += Pivot_SelectionChanged;

    // create a view model for each pivot item.
    for(int i=0;i<pivot.Items.Count;i++)
    {
      PivotItems.Add(new PivotItemViewModel());
    }

    PivotItems[_pivot.SelectedIndex].IsSelected = true;
  }

 private void  Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      var selectedModel = PivotItems.SingleOrDefault(p => p.IsSelected);
    if (selectedModel != null)
      selectedModel.IsSelected = false;

    PivotItems[_pivot.SelectedIndex].IsSelected = true;
  }
}
public class PivotItemViewModelCollection : List<PivotItemViewModel>
{
}

public class PivotItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected == value)
                return;

            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");

            Color = IsSelected ? Colors.Black : Colors.White;
        }
    }

    private Color _color = Colors.White;

    public Color Color
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set
        {
            _color = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Color");
        }
    }

}
```

As a solución I’m thinking about adding this code dynamically instead of using it in the xaml file but have no idea how, any help will be appreciated.

```
<local:PivotLocationView Source="{Binding ElementName=pivot}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                             Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `it’s no longer called once I dynamically add the pivot items.` thx

Comment: It works like this:  If i add the pictures to the project and add them dinamically it all work alright, PivotItemViewModel is called the total pivot items are detected, and everything works ok. If I try to load the images using a list of links in a file using webclient (it takes some time) PivotIttemViewModel is called only for the pivot Item that is already in the xaml file, but once i add the extra pivot items, it is no longer updated, and PivotItemViewModel is no longer called. BTW thanks for your interest in my problem.

Comment: Let me know if i've missed the mark.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you need to make your `pivot` variable a property in your viewmodel then call `OnPropertyChanged` in the property.  Something like this:

XAML code: (notice its bound to the public property Pivot instead of the var pivot)

```
<local:PivoteLocationView="{Binding ElementName=Pivot}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                      Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
```

C# code that will add the pivotitems (notice the Pivot = pivot at the end)

```
pivot.Items.Clear();
for (i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
     //....nothing really changes here
}
Pivot = pivot;
```

Add to the control:

```
public Pivot Pivot
{
    get
    {
        return pivot;
    }
    set
    {
        pivot = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Pivot");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I get the idea, but how do I avoid the "'Pivot is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' error at  the    Pivot = pivot; section.

Comment: There is clearly some code that you are not showing then.  how do you declare `pivot`?

Comment: Oh, that must be occurring in the property.  You will have a the declaration of `pivot` something like `mypivottype pivot = new mypivottype();`  just make the property `public mypivottype Pivot {`